# How to fix python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated: ERROR?

Tags: python, yocto

When I run "bitbake core-image-sato" the following error I am facing.

```
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:sort_passwd(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/A/poky/meta/classes/rootfs-postcommands.bbclass', lineno: 182, function: sort_passwd
     0178:}
     0179:
     0180:python sort_passwd () {
     0181:    import rootfspostcommands
 *** 0182:    rootfspostcommands.sort_passwd(d.expand('${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}'))
     0183:}
     0184:
     0185:#
     0186:# Enable postinst logging if debug-tweaks is enabled
File: '/home/A/poky/meta/lib/rootfspostcommands.py', lineno: 56, function: sort_passwd
     0052:            mapping = sort_file(filename, None)
     0053:            filename = os.path.join(sysconfdir, shadow)
     0054:            remove_backup(filename)
     0055:            if os.path.exists(filename):
 *** 0056:                 sort_file(filename, mapping)
File: '/home/A/poky/meta/lib/rootfspostcommands.py', lineno: 22, function: sort_file
     0018:            name = entries[0]
     0019:            if mapping is None:
     0020:                id = int(entries[2])
     0021:            else:
 *** 0022:                id = mapping[name]
     0023:            new_mapping[name] = id
     0024:        # Sort by numeric id first, with entire line as secondary key
     0025:        # (just in case that there is more than one entry for the same id).
     0026:        lines.sort(key=lambda line: (new_mapping[line.split(b':')[0]], line))
Exception: KeyError: b'bin'
DEBUG: Python function sort_passwd finished
DEBUG: Python function do_rootfs finished
ERROR: Function failed: sort_passwd
```

Does any one has the idea to fix this issue.

OS:Ubuntu-16.04,Poky-Branch:SUMO

Comment: did you installed the yocto with sudo command.

Comment: bitbake command I am not running with sudo command.Also not running as a superuser

Comment: Have you made any changes to your downloaded recipes etc? Or is this a vanilla poky build?

Comment: I'm asking because of the comments above the point where the exception is being thrown:  `No explicit error checking for the sake of simplicity. /etc files are assumed to be well-formed, causing exceptions if not.`

Comment: Check the files in `/etc` in your ROOTFS image

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the contents of any of the following files, which get installed to `/etc`, then that is likely your root cause:

- passwd
- shadow
- group
- gshadow

These files often come from the directory `/files` in one of your layers. It looks like one of them is ill-formatted.

There is a comment in `rootfspostcommands.py`, right above the point where the exception is being thrown, that reads:

```
# No explicit error checking for the sake of simplicity. /etc
# files are assumed to be well-formed, causing exceptions if
# not.
```

Comment: I have changed some of this, what do I do to get it building?

Comment: Sorry, haven't touched yocto for about 3 years, so I have no idea of the current implementations. But basically, make sure the files you are installing are properly formatted(i.e. contain no typos and have the correct number of fields in each line etc)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works for you, please do `bitbake -c clean yourimagename` and make the build again. This method worked for me and maybe it will help you too.

Note: do not do `cleanall` because it is going to delete a lot of files and hence will take more time to make the build from start.